# Epson RC+ line numbers

Tags: industrial-robot

I am programming an EPSON SCARA robot using RC+ 7.4.8. Any error in compiling the program shows in red in the bottom status bar with the error message, program and line number.

This would be wonderful if the program files had line numbers. I have found no mention of this anywhere on the internet or within EPSON's manual etc.

Does anyone know if it is possible to get line numbers in program files on RC+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried looking around online and found a manual for RC+ 4.x that mentioned a "renumber" and "strip line number" command, but the manual for the 7.x version makes no mention of the same, so I downloaded a trial version of the software, looking for those buttons.

I didn't find any way to turn on line numbers in the file, but I *did* see that it's indicated on the bottom-right corner of the screen. Hope this helps!

[image: Epson RC+ line numbers]

Comment: Thanks so much, I hadn't noticed that!

Comment: @E.Aigle Happy to help! :D